# Regression predicting car acceleration in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a file containing ca. 900+ car models manufactured in 2021. In addition, I have technical data on 27 cars however, they miss: **acceleration**, **top speed**, **fuel consumption**, and **CO2-emissions**.

I found out, from a Google search, that for acceleration there exists a formula:
[image]

Now, I have the following information to play with, concerning prediction of the **acceleration**:

- *MaxTorque* (Scale)
- *Gears* (Ordinal, *needs conversion to binary with dummy variables*)
- *EngineTorque* (Ordinal, *needs conversion to binary with dummy variables*)
- *Weight* (Scale)

I am not sure, if **MaxTorque** is the right choice here, because, **EngineTorque** gives many different values for different types of Engines. Now, if, anyone here knows a good way to do this in SPSS, I'd be happy to listen and read.

**EDIT:** *I know very little to nothing about cars or their engines. I know how to drive a car obviously, because I have driving license ;-).*

**Goal:** Predict the missing values by creating 4 different regression models for each column:
[image]

Comment: "Play with" doesn't express an answerable question.  What are you trying to do??

Comment: @whuber, just an expression, what I have at my disposal according to the Google search I made earlier. I pasted the results of that search here. Apparently, **acceleration** is predicted with **torque** times **total gears** divided by **weight** of the car.

Comment: @whuber, please see my **EDIT** with a new screenshot here.

Comment: "Predicting missing values" is usually called *imputation.*  It is rarely an analytical objective in its own right, but is carried out to support some other analysis of the data.  Your choice of an appropriate imputation method will depend on what that ultimate analysis might be: that's the kind of information that will help us understand your question better.

Comment: @whuber, what other information do you need here? I am new to regression analysis, and the tasks clearly and strictly says: "using regression to create 4 different regression models to predict missing values", **Acceleration**, **Top Speed**, **FuelConsumption**, and **CO2-emissions** of the cars that are missing these values.

Comment: That's the problem with homework exercises: they are rarely well motivated, often artificial, and raise questions that cannot be answered.  Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info.

Comment: @whuber, https://www.slideshare.net/ShankarPrasaadRajama/auto-mpg-regression-analysis-130052605

Comment: @whuber, so, how can this be done in SPSS? I created *dummy variables* as **binary**, but, I am guessing, the regression model will not, or how will it really use these bits to provide a way to predict **acceleration** here.

Comment: Questions about how to operate SPSS (or any other software) are not on topic here.